# Resolve dns (edns) with client subnet option in Python

Tags: python, dns

I'm looking for an implementation in Python that would allow me to resolve a DNS address using an extension of DNS (EDNS) "client sub options" . This option allows better DNS-resolution for content delivery systems - and ultimately, faster internet routing. The motivation is better explained here: http://www.afasterinternet.com/howitworks.htm

another name for this is "vandergaast-edns-client-subnet"

an implementation for dig is available here:
https://www.gsic.uva.es/~jnisigl/dig-edns-client-subnet.html

I'm looking for a python implementation that would do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the developer/maintainer of dnspython-clientsubnet.  It is designed to be used in your code as an additive to dnspython.  I've just released version 2.0.0 (after trying to do what you wanted) which makes everything much easier

1. `pip install clientsubnetoption` (works for both Python2 & Python3)
2. Import `clientsubnetoption` and dependancies you'll need:

   ```
   import dns
   import clientsubnetoption
   ```
3. Setup your `ClientSubnetOption` with the information you want:

   ```
   cso = clientsubnetoption.ClientSubnetOption('1.2.3.4')
   ```
4. Create your DNS packet:

   ```
   message = dns.message.make_query('google.com', 'A')
   ```
5. Add the edns option:

   ```
   message.use_edns(options=[cso])
   ```
6. Use `message` to make your query:

   ```
   r = dns.query.udp(message, '8.8.8.8')
   ```
7. Option information is now at `r.options` and there can be multiple, so you may need to iterate through them to find the `ClientSubnetOption` object.

   ```
   for options in r.options:
       if isinstance(options, ClientSubnetOption):
           # do stuff here
           pass
   ```

The code in clientsubnetoption.py is there to act as a unit test and a testing tool for support of edns-clientsubnet, not because you have to use it that way.

Answer (score 1):

A python implementation exists:
its an extension of dnspython (http://www.dnspython.org/) that can be found here: https://github.com/opendns/dnspython-clientsubnetoption

1. pip install dnspython
2. git clone the repo from github
3. use this command:

   python clientsubnetoption.py (name-server) (host to query>)  -s (client-ip) -m 32
4. Note that the repo does not actually print the results. its just a tester, so it just emits "success" or "failure". To get the actual results you'll need to modify the python code to print the response from the DNS server.